# What is 't Hooft-Veltman gauge? What are the interactions in SM in 't Hooft-Veltman gauge?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, definition, yang-mills, gauge

What is 't Hooft-Veltman gauge? I can't really find any suitable answer online. If we introduce this gauge in SM, then what becomes interactions?

Comment: [This seems to cover it](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321319302366).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the 't Hooft-Veltman gauge
$$ G~=~ \partial_{\mu} A^{\mu} +\frac{\lambda}{2} A_{\mu} A^{\mu} $$
is a non-linear deformation of the [Lorenz gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition)
$$G~=~ \partial_{\mu} A^{\mu} .$$
This modifies the Feynman-rules for the interaction vertices but not the propagators.

References:

1. R. B. Mann, G. McKeon & S.B. Phillips, *Longitudinal contributions to the vacuum polarization in the't Hooft-Veltman gauge,* [Can. J. Phys. 62 (1984) 1129](https://doi.org/10.1139/p84-156).
2. G. McKeon, S.B. Phillips, S.S. Samant & T.N. Sherry, *Becchi-Rouet-Stora invariance in the 't Hooft-Veltman gauge,* [Can. J. Phys. 63 (1985) 1343](https://doi.org/10.1139/p85-222).

Comment: Thank you very much.